# ListView/ListAdapter paging

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement paging in a custom ListAdapter.  Right now I'm just making the request for the next page when the last item in the ListView becomes visible, by checking in `getView()` if `position` is `>=` the size of `ListAdapter.getCount()`.

It works fine, but I'm wondering if there's a better way (or a different way) that will only make the request once the last item in the list is actually visible to the user.  Anyone know of a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm doing it almost the same way:

```
public static final int SCROLLING_OFFSET = 5;
// ...
private final ArrayList<T> items = new ArrayList<T>();
// ...
if (SCROLLING_OFFSET == items.size() - position) {
    if (hasNextPage()) {
        addNextPage();
    }
}

private boolean hasNextPage() {
    // basically calculates whether the last 2 pages contained the same # of items
}

private void addNextPage() {
    // show spinner
    // fetch next page in a background thread
    // add to items
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a better way to do it. Implementing the `OnScrollListener` interface. Take a look at this: [Endless Scrolling ListView](http://benjii.me/2010/08/endless-scrolling-listview-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the check altogether. In my experience, getView() is only called when the entry is about to come on screen.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  The check has to be there, else it would page every row?